# How do I use the same post slug for different Categories?

Tags: categories, permalinks, slug

I want to use the same post slug for different categories. Because I will have different projects with the same slug. I already have the post slug `email`. The second slug `email` becomes `email-2`, but I don't want that.

For example, I will have different projects for email:

```
www.example.com/category-one/email
www.example.com/category-two/email
www.example.com/category-three/email
```

Comment: Assumption here that the 3 pages with the slug of email are all different?

Comment: yes is different

Answer (score 5):

### Using Parent-Child Page (Recommended)

If you don't have to have categories & posts, then this can be easily achieved using parent-child pages (not posts).

For example, say you have three pages like:

```
www.example.com/category-one/
www.example.com/category-two/
www.example.com/category-three/
```

Now you can have child pages for the above pages with slug `email`, e.g.

```
www.example.com/category-one/email
www.example.com/category-two/email
www.example.com/category-three/email
```

This is possible because WordPress considers the entire parent-child combination slug for pages (or any other hierarchical post type) to be unique.

Of course, all these child pages with `email` slug are different pages, just with the same ending URL slug.

### Using Category-Post combination

> **Warning:** By default WordPress doesn't support this & for good reason. May be now you have `/%category%/%postname%/` as your current permalink structure, but what if it needs to be changed in the future? Then you'll have conflicts.
>
> Also, since WordPress doesn't support this internally, you may have unforeseen issues with other plugins (e.g. custom permalink plugins, SEO plugins etc.).

This is possible using the [`wp_unique_post_slug`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_unique_post_slug/) filter hook. for example, the following sample Plugin will allow multiple occurrences of the `email` slug:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  WPSE non-unique post slug
Plugin URI:   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/313422/110572
Description:  WPSE non-unique post slug
Version:      1.0.0
Author:       Fayaz Ahmed
Author URI:   https://www.fayazmiraz.com/
*/

add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'wpse313422_non_unique_post_slug', 10, 6 );

function wpse313422_non_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ) {
    if( $post_type === 'post' && $original_slug === 'email' ) {
        // Perform category conflict, permalink structure
        //     and other necessary checks.
        // Don't just use it as it is.
        return $original_slug;
    }

    return $slug;
}
```