# Wordpress/NGINX not respecting the category URL for new posts

Tags: php, permalinks, urls, nginx

Only recently noticed this issue with my site configurations, it seems as though on my NGINX Wordpress sites the category base of a URL is not being respected and instead being redirected to another category which uses the same post_name slug as the new post. This results in me unable to make any unique name posts since it's ignoring the category base entirely!

I'm not entirely sure why this is the case and would love if someone could help with this. Details below.

An example expected scenario

http://mywebsite.com/category-1/post-1  => will go to /category-1/post-1
http://mywebsite.com/category-2/post-1  => will go to /category-2/post-1

Current scenario

http://mywebsite.com/category-1/post-1  => will go to /category-1/post-1
http://mywebsite.com/category-2/post-1  => will go to /category-1/post-1

Any new posts will produce the following

http://mywebsite.com/category-1/post-1  => post exists at /category-1/post-1
http://mywebsite.com/category-2/post-1  => new post created with exists at /category-2/post-1-2 extension

My settings in the permalinks for Wordpress 
[image]

My NGINX configurations for /location is below

```
    location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    # break if URI has .html extension
    if ($request_filename ~* ^.+.html$) {
      break;
    }
    # add .html to URI and serve file, directory, or symlink if it exists
    if (-e $request_filename.html) {
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1.html last;
      break;
    }


    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; 

#   try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, and I might be wrong so I'm not posting as an answer, WordPress post slugs need to be unique regardless of whether the category is in the URL So I don't believe NGINX is relevant here. This may just the be the expected behaviour of WordPress.

Comment: Note that when I say "expected behaviour" I only mean expected based on how WordPress is coded, not what an end user would expect.

Comment: I think you might be right, after a further dig based on your assumption I found re: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313422/how-do-i-use-the-same-post-slug-for-different-categoriesthat posts do indeed need to be unique D: I was under the impression that it worked the same way pages worked. I think I'll just have to move all the posts into pages